# C++ Alt-Tab Hook

Tags: c++, dll, keyboard, hook

I've looked at some sample code to develop a <kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>tab</kbd> keyboard hook but I don't seem to understand the whole thing. I understand that a .dll is written and that somehow gets injected to all the processes.

Is there a top to bottom guide on how to do this from writing the dll to loading it?

Comment: I'm not sure if a keyboard hook is the right answer to this one. I'd tend to use a message hook on the process that registered the original Alt+Tab hotkey.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: `Alt+Tab` is a system-defined hotkey for toggling between open windows.  It is not an application-defined hotkey.

Comment: @SirRoot: what exactly do you not understand about it?  It is pretty straight-forward.  The DLL implements a callback function to handle the keyboard events, then either the DLL or the EXE calls `SetWindowsHookEx()` to register that callback with the OS.  Hooks are chained, so when the callback gets called, it needs to call `CallNextHookEx()` to pass the data to the next hook in the chain.  When you are finished hooking the keyboard, call `UnhookWindowsHookEx()` to release your hook.  What is confusing about that?

Comment: well for starters I've never written my own dll before let alone loaded one.

Comment: @Remy are you sure it's not registered by some user-mode program that's part of windows? On Win7 the instance of explorer.exe that displays the shell replaces the Alt+Tab behavior, and I strongly doubt it does it with a keyboard hook. So I assume there is a better way to replace Alt+Tab than using a keyboard hook.

Comment: @SirRoot if you want to go the keyboard hook way, consider using a lowlevel keyboard hook. They are much easier to write, don't get injection into other processes,...

Comment: @CodeInChaos: even if you were to hook explorer directly instead of the keyboard, a DLL is still needed since you are hooking into another process, so the coding logic is very similar to a keyboard hook (though it is actually a bit harder to write a hook for a specific process since you have to hunt down that process and grab its thread ID before installing the hook).

Answer (score 1):

Keyboard hooks are a really shared resource, i.e. it depends on programs not stomping on each other. It's always a bit risky to insert one into the chain. Can I ask what the hook is for? What is it you're trying to ultimately accomplish with the hook?

Comment: I want to disable the closing of my software because I'm doing some experiments with windows XP embedded. I don't want the user using alt-tab, control-alt-del , or anything to get behind the main use of the system and fish around the OS. I read that a keyboard filter or hook was the only way to prevent alt-tab, unless there is another way?